# Multivendor functionality integrate the "Paypal Adaptive Payments"

Tags: payment

customer buys products from vendor A, vendor B and vendor C.

Will the customer pay the full amount for product A, B and C and then Paypal will deliver it to the correspondent vendor automatically or customer will should confirm transactions for each vendor ?